# Central repository for Crystal Shards?

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there anything like NPM or pip for Crystal?

Are there plans or a roadmap to achieve this?

I have gotten tired of copying and pasting github repositories into my shards file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependency manager for Crystal is `shards`. However, different from `npm` or `pip`, there is no centralized repository for registering shards. This has some benefits, among them avoiding a critical point of failure.

For the process of configuring your shard dependencies, this makes no significant difference. It's just that instead of adding a registered name, you put in the address of a repository.

Currently, there is no option to add a shard to your shards file directly from the command line (but there is [an issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/shards/issues/144) for that) so you have to edit `shards.yml` and add it manually.

Honestly, I don't think this is much of a disturbance. I can't remember using a command line tool to add a local dependency even if many dependency managers support that. If you're adding a dependency, you'll also have to add code to use it. So you'll need to work in an editor anyway and can easily edit the dependency file there.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what the other benefits would be? The critical point of failure is a big one, but what else is there?

Comment: Another big one is: nobody needs to maintain a registry - this costs money, time and effort.
Then, there can't be any name clashes. And it's a native feature to integrate sources from anywhere (for example private repositories).